# AIX: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" but the library exists

Tags: java, unix, java-native-interface, aix

I'm using JNI to call a shared library named "libmy_jni.so" from my java code. Those are working good without any problem in other OS's but in AIX, I see the following error. I've checked that the LIBPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH(in case) are set correctly and matched x86 module with 32bit java(and x64 with 64bit java).

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: my_jni (No such file or directory)
```

The java code loading the library is,

```
File sofile = new File("libmy_jni.so");

if(!sofile.exists())
{
        System.out.println("can't find the moudle.");
        System.exit(1);
}

System.loadLibrary("my_jni");
```

As I know, the most cases causing the error above are incorrect library path or unmatched 32/64bit architecture. But in my case I don't see what could be the reason.

```
>>file libmy_jni.so
libmy_jni.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
```

Comment: Could this be a dependency of libmy_jni.so that is not there? On Linux you would check with ldd. Don't know what AIX's equivalent is.

Comment: Try this option: `-Djava.library.path=.`